# How to draw image that was clicked using canvas and save it using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, canvas

I'm using canvas to draw 2 images one into another. But there is click event. I want to put this image that was clicked on the first image and save it.

I got this error:
`TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement`

Here's my code:

```js
 window.onload = function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var img = document.getElementById("background");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
   
    $('body').on('click', '.add-image', function () {
                var src = $(this).attr('src');

                var bomb = document.getElementById("add-image");
             

                ctx.drawImage(bomb, 50, 50);
     }
                 
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="1100"
                            style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
                        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
                    </canvas>

                    <div id="background-image-holder">
                       <span style="display:none;">
                        <img src="<?php echo $path;?>" class="background" id="background">
                        
                    </div>
                      
                       <?php if(!empty($images)) { foreach($images as $image) { echo $images;  ?>
                                <div >
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image_path . $image['image'];?>" class="add-image" id"add-image">
                                </div>
                            <?php } } ?>
```

Edited: How to save image using Ajax? I tried the following but there is no image:
I did it, I have overwritten canvas variable. :)

```js
 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  console.log(dataURL);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
                                  
      url: "<?php echo URL::base();?>images/upload",
      data: {data: dataURL},
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
                                         
      }
});
```

Comment: What's the element `#add-bomb` in your page, can't find it. Another one: Your php seems to generate many `img` with same `id`, it also has a typo, ` id"add-image"` miss `=`.

Comment: My element is #add-image, my mistake. But yes, it's in loop. How to get clicked image

Comment: Your `$(this)` in that click handler is the clicked img. Use `var clickedImg = $(this).get(0);` and `ctx.drawImage(clickedImg , 50, 50);` should work.

Comment: @RayonDabre calling a string in `ctx.drawImage` won't work

Comment: @Kaiido, Ooh yeah! `ctx.drawImage(this, 50, 50);` will do right !

Comment: Thank you, it's working!

Comment: How to save images from canvas element using Ajax? I edited my question.